# Any Equivalent of ReorderList Control in Winform?

Tags: winforms

ASP.NET has a reorderlist control

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ReorderList/ReorderList.aspx

Is there anything equivalent (control, source code, ...) in Winform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ObjectListView](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2) -- an open source wrapper around a WinForms ListView -- has the ability to rearrange objects in the list through dragging, much like the demo you gave.

Have a look at the "Drag and Drop" tab in the demo and read [this recipe](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/dragdrop.html#rearranging-rows-by-dragging).

[image]